# How to stop LongRunning task being waiting on Monitor.Wait when application shuts down?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a long running Task that internally blocks on Monitor.Wait with no timeout. My class has a Dispose method that allows it to unblock and then wait for that task to complete. However, in some usages my clients won't call Dispose at all, which causes the Task remain blocked forever.
Will this be an issue?
How can I signal that task when the client application is shutting down?
I'm thinking about using of a Finalize method, but it seems error prone to me.

EDIT:
I have found a nice article explaining a lot of such things in just few pages:
http://www.albahari.info/threading/threading.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got into this pickle by abusing Dispose().  Client code is not likely to use it when it is shutting down, there's just no point in disposing unmanaged resources early when the finalizer runs a millisecond later anyway.

But it is not an issue.  A long running Task uses a thread that has its [IsBackground property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) set to true.  Which saves your bacon, the CLR will automatically terminate the thread when it shuts down.  There is no scenario where that blocked Task can prevent the program from ending normally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a `Monitor.PulseAll(Object)` using the instance of the object upon your `Monitor.Wait(Object)` is holding.

From MSDN:

> **Monitor.PulseAll**
>
> Notifies all waiting threads of a change in the object's state.

The solutions are

- ensure that you carefully manage the lifetime of objects that use `Monitor` methods
- `Thread.Abort`. Absolutely horrible idea but no doubt someone will mention it. It will get the job done by it may leave things in a mess.
- before you call `Monitor.Wait`, register the `object` parameter with a static field that you can use to `PulseAll` at any period. I can't recommend this as good design but it is a nice bandaid fix.